# Restarting expo app on logout without ejecting

Tags: authentication, expo

I would like to reload the entire expo application when I click on the logout function and I want to do it without ejecting the application, is there a workaround for this? Any help would be appreciated. I have researched on the react-native-restart library but it requires me to eject my application.

These are my current codes

```
  logOut() {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
      bypassCache: false  
    }).
      then(
        user => user.signOut()
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
import { Updates } from 'expo';
Updates.reload()
```

It's [generally used to reload apps when new update is available](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/updates/), but should also work in your case

Comment: Just a quick heads up that this package will soon be a separate module and in there, `Updates.reload()` has been [removed](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/updates/#legacy-api).

Comment: @DarrylYoung So what can be used now?

Comment: @Aido As far as I know, there's no direct replacement. It's been removed from the API and looking at the documentation there's no replacement command. I'll update if I find another way.

Answer (score 0):

After expo remove

```
Updates.reload()
```

then you can use

```
await Updates.reloadAsync()
```

to reload application instead.